# If I delete all photos on my phone, will contacts pictures also be deleted?

Tags: contacts, images, delete

If I delete all photos on my phone, will contacts pictures also be deleted?

I have pictures that I use for some of my contacts.  The picture is what shows up when they call or if I text them (the little square picture on the side).

-samsung note 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Contacts' pictures are kept separately from the original photos you added them from. They're stored with the contacts database, not with the photos on the SD card. Deleting photos from the Gallery app or wiping the SD card won't affect them.